# Can pip show me the version of the python package I just installed?

Tags: python, version, pip

I initially installed a version of python-git (GitPython) on my machine. It was version 0.1. Then I used pip to upgrade it to the latest. Now I was looking for the appropriate docs and fell unsure of which version I actually installed. So how to find the version of the installed python package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
pip list | grep -i package
```

package name could be segment of the package name and is case insensitive.

output:

```
package (0.0.0)
```

the red highlight shows your search criteria.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, pip can show list of packages installed and versions.

```
pip list
```

Output:

```
amqp (1.4.6)
beautifulsoup4 (4.3.2)
caniusepython3 (2.2.0)
certifi (14.05.14)
coverage (3.7.1)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually a command line like this does it on UNIX:

```
  ls /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages|grep -i packagename
```

All eggs live in site-packages folder and they have version number in their folder / .egg file name.

Your question lacks operating system details and what Python was used to install, so it is not possible to give the exact answer.